# A generic error occurred in GDI+ (screenshot SaveAsFile, ExternalException)

Tags: c#, file, selenium, path, screenshot

Hello I tried looking through questions that may have my answer but none of them did.

I am doing web automation testing and trying to take a screenshot of when an error occurs and save it to a file in another folder.

My program has a 30 second timeout when searching for elements on the page. If after 30 seconds no element is found, it takes a SS, reloads the page, and tries again.

The first screenshot works fine. But on the second run through, it tries to save another screenshot to the folder and I get this incredibly vague error that is seemingly caused by a hundred different things, so I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Here's my code:

```
public void takeScreenShot()
    {
        string ssPath = _persistencePath += "\\Errors";

        string currTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MMM-ddd-d-HH.mm");

        Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();

        try
        {
            ss.SaveAsFile(ssPath + "\\ERROR-" + currTime + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            ssCount = 0;
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
        {
            ssCount++;

            //error occurs here
            ss.SaveAsFile(ssPath + "\\ERROR-" + currTime + "(" + ssCount + ")" + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

I initially thought the issue was that it was trying to save a file of the same name, because if the error happens during the same minute then the file name is the same. So that's why I added that catch block, in an attempt to change the name if it occurs in the same minute. But that didn't fix it.

Again I tried searching all over and couldn't find an answer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code of GetScreenshot?

Comment: I'm guessing you think that your `catch` will loop (loop counter in there) and you are using it as a poor-mans file name verification. If you throw inside a catch, it will exit the catch and move up the chain to the next catch, if there is none then the application will throw an exception.

Comment: Also, let us know what line you get the error on, its not apparent. Instead of using the time, I would use a Guid in the file name (`Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`), while not 100% unique, its unique enough that name collisions should be very, very rare. You can use the file time to sort.

Comment: The error occurs on the ss.SaveAsFile in the catch block. I also tried removing the try/catch altogether and adding seconds to the file name, but i'm still getting the error. i also saw what you said about selenium's SaveAsFile overwriting one with the same name, so now i just have aboslutely no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Often vague errors have informative `InnerException` properties, check to see if there is an `InnerException` and let us know what it is.

Comment: InnerException is null. So what's my next course of action? Also, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: One more thing, try changing your filename to remove the .mm (it may be causing confusion with file types). Also, if ss (Screenshot) is Disposable, use a Finally block and call ss.Dispose so you make sure it releases its resources.

Comment: Just looking at the Selenium source (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Screenshot.cs) its not Disposable, and they do not dispose of the Image object when done, this may be a bug in Selenium. Try calling GC.Collect to see if it cleans up the Image.

Comment: The exception is just not specific enough to give a hint.  *Any* failure to write the file will cause this exception.  Could be locked file, bad directory, bad filename, full disk, path too long.  But also a problem with the image itself, like a disposed MemoryStream.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to get more diagnostics.

Comment: @RonBeyer I tried removing the .mm, same issue. In regards to the dispose thing - would that really matter? Every time I call this method it's creating a new Screenshot object, so would disposing have an effect?

Comment: @HansPassant doesn't the fact that the first attempt at taking a screenshot is successful mean that the file isn't locked, the directory isn't bad, the filename isn't bad, (the disk is not full) and the path isn't too long? If it were just blowing up from the get-go instead of successfully working once and THEN throwing an error, this would make a lot more sense. But thanks, I'll look into SysInternals Process Monitor.

Comment: They are disposable because they use unmanaged resources, its important they be disposed of: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Image@cs/1/Image@cs if you are interested in the code.

Comment: If thats the case, a workaround may be to use the Screenshot.AsByteArray to create (and dispose of) your own image. I'll post an answer that shows how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if anyone's curious I solved it. Turns out I'm just an idiot.

```
string ssPath = _persistencePath += "\\Errors";
```

this line was appending another \Errors to the target path on the second run though. thus invalidating the path, because \Errors\Errors didn't exist.

Thanks to everyone who commented/tried to help!

Comment: You can use `Directory.CreateDirectory(path);` to ensure the folders are created (if they don't exist yet)

Comment: The error should have just said, path does not exist.. instead of GDI+ generic error :D

Comment: Haha, we ran into the same kind of issue. Thanks for saving us some time. Btw you are not an idiot at all, the exception is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The Screenshot class doesn't dispose of the image resource properly, so it may be a bug in the Selenium framework. A work-around is to do it yourself:

```
public void takeScreenShot()
{
    string ssPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_persistencePath, @"\Errors");

    string currTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MMM-ddd-d-HH.mm");
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ssPath, @"\ERROR-" + currTime + ".png");

    Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ss.AsByteArray))
    using (Image screenShotImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        Bitmap cp = new Bitmap(screenShotImage);
        cp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
        cp.Dispose();
    }
}
```

No assurance that this will fix it, but at least you can be reasonable assured that the resources are disposed of properly.

**Note** requires you to reference `System.Drawing.dll` in the project.

**Edit** another workaround posted.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain to me what's going on and offer a solution. Unfortunately that did not work. In fact, with the above implementation for some reason the first screenshot isn't even taken. However if i remove all the System.IO.Path.Combine stuff, then it DOES take the first screenshot, but then throws the error again on the second attempt.

Comment: @kdeez one more time, I found another work-around that may help, you can use it without the Path.Combine stuff. Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't have access to ImageFormat however. I am referencing System.Drawing.dll, so i don't know what's up with that...

Comment: Just use the whole name as you did in your post, `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png`

Comment: Hah. Sorry, brain fart. it's been a long day already. But I tried it out, and still no luck :\    Thanks anyways though, I really appreciate you taking time out of your day to try and help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it!

check out this, just write completed PATHNAME,

```
pathname+filename+extension: @"C:\folderWithPermission\test.bmp"
```

JUST TAKE FOLDER WITH WRITE PERMISSIONS, was like o.0

here's the method

```
 public DriverExecutor CaptureScreen(string filename)
    {
        Screenshot shot = this.myRemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot();
        MemoryStream ms;
        Image imgShot;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try 
        {
            using (ms = new MemoryStream(shot.AsByteArray))
            using (imgShot = Image.FromStream(ms))
            using (bitmap = new Bitmap(imgShot))
            {
                bitmap.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
        }catch(Exception err){}
        return this;
    }
```

NOTE: im asssuming what remoteDriver was rightly instanced and encapsulated on a own object , i hope this help you all ^^